# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath' when using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url = 'https://movie.douban.com/subject/1292052/'
data = requests.get(url).text
s=etree.HTML(data)

film=s.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/h1/span[1]/text()')

print('film_title：',film)
```

but I got an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-4e3f3aa89a1c>", line 8, in <module>
    film=s.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/h1/span[1]/text()')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

I don't know why this happen and how to correct it.

Comment: Because you are getting 418 as a response. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52340027/is-418-im-a-teapot-really-an-http-response-code

Comment: use raise_for_status of response object to get an idea about what HTTP status you're getting and incase of non 2XX codes handle it https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.5.3/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes

Answer (score 0):

You can add a header to simulate a browser

headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.163 Safari/535.1'}

url = 'https://movie.douban.com/subject/1292052/'

data = requests.get(url,headers = headers).text